# Color Box Popup on radio button checked

Tags: jquery, html, popup, colorbox

I have two radio buttons and I want to open popup model when one of the radio button is checked. I know how colorbox works with anchor but it doesn't seem to work with radio button.
any help or sample code?

This is HTML

```
 <div class="radio-button ">
    <input type="radio" id="checkboxecheck" />
    <a href="#popup-modal" class="cbox"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="hide">
    <div id="popup-modal" class="alert-container ">
         This message should be in model popup.
    </div>
 </div>
```

this is java script code

```
$(function () {
        $('#checkboxecheck').on('click', function () {
            $('.cbox').colorbox({
                transition: "none",
                inline: true,
                fixed: true,
                width: "350px",
                hideCloseButton: true,
                overlayClose: true,
                opacity: "0.5"
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you please provide any code you have so far? Maybe a http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: what are your radios? what is the intent of radios here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
       $('selector').colorbox();// you can change it with your options
    });
});
```

Comment: hi Rohan, my code is similar to you but it still not working may be i am creating any mistake that is out of my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> $("#yourCheckboxID").change(function () {
>
> ```
>             if (this.checked) {
>
>                 //Some instructions
>             }
> ```
>
> });

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function () {
        $(".cbox").colorbox({ 
            inline: true,
            width: "350px", 
            scrolling: false, 
            close: "X", 
            returnFocus: false,
            trapFocus: false 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include an explanation of your code? It helps the reader more than you might think.

Comment: When page is loaded then its first load all html,images than its run its jquery. so during page load all images with in slider will be shown. what we can do hide all images during page load and show them just before slider call.

Comment: To hide your slider image do following as number of your slides

<div class="hide">
    <div class="iframe-video" id="myForm">
        <iframe width="888" height="668" src="http://mysite.local/presentation/desktop/IframeVideo.aspx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

    **CSS**

.hide
{
display:none;

Answer (score 0):

```
            Hi,

            I am using Colorbox for open Popup and you can download colorbox by this link.


 - http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/


            You can do this by using this code:

            <head>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" type="text/css" />

                <script type="text/javascript">
                   $(document).ready(function ($) {
                        $('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function () {              
                            $('#popup-modal').addClass("show");
                            $.colorbox({
                                width: "60%",
                                height: "60%",
                                inline: true,
                                href: "#popup-modal",
                                onClosed: function () {                      
                                    $('#popup-modal').removeClass("show");
                                    $('#popup-modal').addClass("hide");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>

               <style type="text/css">
                    .hide {
                        display: none;
                    }
                    .show {
                        display: inline;
                    }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                    <div class="radio-button">
                        <input type="radio" id="checkboxecheck_In" name="SameGroup" />In
                        <input type="radio" id="checkboxecheck_Out" name="SameGroup" />Out            
                    </div>

                    <%--This div open in Popup--%>
                    <div id="popup-modal" class="hide">
                        This message should be in model popup.
                    </div>
        </body>
```